# How much is the bus fare from Buenos Aires downtown to EZE airport

Tags: buses, fares, buenos-aires

I'm trying to figure out what bus fares in Buenos Aires are. I have read various websites but the quoted numbers are all over the place and because of the rapid inflation, prices change quickly.

I got the Sube payment card but I don't know how much to put on to it. Since the trip to the airport will be the last time I will be using the card, I don't want to overcharge it either.

Specific questions;

- Is there an "official" website that gives the current price for Buenos Aires bus fares ?
- Is there a "safe" upper limit for a bus trip from Plaza De Majo to EZE airport (line 8E) of what it might cost right now ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

The Argentinian government [publishes a list of fares](https://www.argentina.gob.ar/redsube/tarifas-de-transporte-publico-amba-2021) for public transport in the Buenos Aires region. [Bus](https://dle.rae.es/colectivo) fares top out at 23 pesos as of this writing, and subway fares at 30, though, as you note, the rapid inflation in Argentina means that price rises are possible on short notice. There are [discounts available](https://www.argentina.gob.ar/redsube) if your trip involves more than one form of transport.

Answer (score 1):

And here is the answer. @mic was correct:

- As of July 3rd, 2022 to bus fare from 699 De Mayo to EZE airport
  using line 8A air is 23 Peso. As of today that's less than US$0.18 at the official rate and less than a dime if you can get the "blue" rate.
- It's a whopping 95
  stops and takes almost 2 hours.
- Line 8 has 5 "flavors" A, B, C, D and E. 8E (supposedly marked
  "Autopista X") is apparently the "express" version and "may" be more
  expensive. But I wasn't able to find one and I'm pretty sure they are
  not going on Sundays.
- The experience is actually quite interesting and fun if you into this sort of thing. Avoid if you

  - are in a hurry or have a tight schedule
  - don't like getting up, close, and personal with the locals (which are quite friendly)
  - have heavy or bulky luggage. There is no storage space on the bus
  - have a sensitive derrière: the busses are fine but they are regular commuter busses and there are some impressive speed bumps.
  - have a small bladder: there is no loo on the bus.

The fare structure is puzzling: even the shortest bus ride (5 stops) that I took cost 20 pesos and 23 for a 95-stop monstrosity doesn't seem a reasonable difference. It does make the "check in" process a lot more complicated and slower: you need to tell the driver where you are going so he can deduct the correct fare from your card. That can be challenging when you don't speak the language.

Trying to find where the bus stops are and when they come isn't easy. Google Maps seems to be the best shot. Some websites recommend [Cuando SUBO](https://cuandosubo.sube.gob.ar/onebusaway-webapp/where/iphone/) but I found it to be very inaccurate and mostly useless. This being said, busses come quite frequently so in general it's ok to just show up and wait.